# Calling the resource compiler from a makefile

Tags: dll, makefile, versioning

I am trying to add some version number information to a dll being compiled using a makefile. I have created an .rc file that builds using rc.exe, however rc.exe builds the .res file in the location of the rc file. rather than the current directory. I need the .res file to build to the build location, so am using the /fo option. The problem is I would like to generate the same build file name that rc.exe creates, simply have it output to the current build folder.

On advice I have developed the following makefile section, but it complains of a missing ')':

```
{$(START_DIR)\..\common}.rc{$(START_DIR)\..\common}.res:
    @cmd /C "echo ### Compiling $<"
    $(RC) /fo .\$(patsubst %.rc, %.res, $(notdir $<)) $<
```

The intent is to take the file name from the path of the source (`$<`) and develop a new path substituting the current directory `.\` for the source directory, the file name of the source, and the .rc extension for the compiled .res extension. This developed path is then put to the /fo option, and then the linker will find it in the current build path.

This is all borne out of the annoyance that rc.exe seems to behave differently to cl.exe, in that cl.exe will build all to the current directory, rc.exe will build to the source directory. If there were a simpler solution to this I could avoid this trouble with the makefile.

**EDIT:** Minimum complete example

```
\test
\test\test.rc
\test\output
\test\output\test.mk
\test\output\test.bat
```

*test.rc*

```
#include <windows.h>
//#include <winnt.h>


LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US

VS_VERSION_INFO    VERSIONINFO
  FILEVERSION      1,0,0,1
  PRODUCTVERSION   1,0,0,1
  FILEFLAGSMASK    0x3fL // VS_FFI_FILEFLAGSMASK
#ifdef _DEBUG
  FILEFLAGS        0x1L  // VS_FF_DEBUG|VS_FF_PRIVATEBUILD|VS_FF_PRERELEASE
#else
  FILEFLAGS        0x0L  // final version
#endif
  FILEOS           VOS_NT_WINDOWS32
  FILETYPE         VFT_APP
  FILESUBTYPE      VFT2_UNKNOWN // not used
BEGIN
  BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
  BEGIN
    BLOCK "040904E4" // Lang=US English, CharSet=Windows Multilingual
    BEGIN
      VALUE "Build",            "August 2007\0"
      VALUE "Comments",         "Free for personal use only.\0"
      VALUE "CompanyName",      "Fake Company\0"
      VALUE "Developer",        "The Developer\0"
      VALUE "FileDescription",  "Application implementing something\0"
      VALUE "FileVersion",      "1.0.000\0"
      VALUE "InternalName",     "AppInternalName\0"
      VALUE "LegalCopyright",   "Copyright (C) 2007 Fake Company\0"
      VALUE "LegalTrademarks",  "All rights reserved.\0"
      VALUE "OriginalFilename", "TheEXE.exe\0"
      VALUE "PrivateBuild",     "\0"
      VALUE "ProductName",      "The EXE\0"
      VALUE "ProductVersion",   "1.0.000\0"
      VALUE "SpecialBuild",     "\0"
      VALUE "Support",          "TheEXE at fake-domain.com\0"
      VALUE "Users",            "Unlimited.\0"
    END // BLOCK "040904E4"
  END // BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
  BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
  BEGIN
    VALUE "Translation", 0x409, 1252 // 1252 = 0x04E4
  END // BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
END'
```

*test.mk:*

```
{..\}.rc.res:
    @cmd /C "echo ### Compiling $<"
    $(RC) /fo .\$(patsubst %.rc,%.res,$(notdir $<)) $<
```

*test.bat:*

```
call "%VS100COMNTOOLS%..\..\VC\bin\vcvars64" 

cd .
nmake -f test.mk
pause
```

From the test\output\ folder run the batch file.

Comment: I can't reproduce this error. Can you give a [minimal complete example](http://www.sscce.org/)? Maybe you could eliminate one of the commands, simplify the other one, simplify the target name,...

Comment: I would probably suggest using `$(basename $(notdir $<)).res` instead of the `patsubst` to generate the output name and you definitely don't want the the spaces after the commas in the `patsubst` call.

Comment: @Beta, done, @Etan, I tried removing the spaces (as in the example) and using `basename`, both have the same error.